# Why was this question opened?

Tags: discussion

Today someone numbered the questions in https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/6413/what-should-be-the-ideal-approach-to-start-automation-testing-on-new-project, but aside from that  formatting change, the content is no different.  The question was on hold; why was it reopened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer. I am trying to be nice :-).

Long answer. The new on hold is designed to give people a chance to update the question before it is just closed. I put it on hold, someone kindly updated it so I decided to re-open it to give it a run we can always close it again.

Comment: I'm all for being nice, but if you look at the difference between the held version and the subsequent edited version, you will see that nothing substantive changed about the question.  As far as I can tell, the reason for putting the question on hold has not changed.  But perhaps you noticed something that I didn't.

Comment: No worries .. I'll on hold it again.

Comment: @BruceMcLeod, Hey, we can't see the question. Is it still there?

Comment: @Pacerier The system has "deleted" the question as it was not updated after a period of time when it was put "on hold" the question is still there but only moderators can see it.

Comment: @BruceMcLeod, Do non-mod high-repperes also get view access?

Comment: @Pacerier to be honest I don't know. I know that really high rep users do get some mod style access.